# How to create a Visualforce page with attachment to specific record?

Tags: apex, attachment

I am modifying Jeff Dougles' code found on his '[Customizing attachments](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2014/05/30/how-to-customize-salesforce-attachments/)' blog to take the concept of creating a way to upload attachments to a custom object.

However I'm doing this via sites so no login is required to the system.  What I am doing is a user will receive a URL like [this](http://fifedom-developer-edition.na1.force.com/guns/Stage_Submission?Id=a0G3000000H744X). This URL has the ID of the record I want to save the record to.

My problem is I don't know how to modify the code to pass in the URL parameter.  Right now I'm just hard coding the ID.

My modified APEX class from Mr. Dougles below.  The line "**obj.id = 'a0G3000000H744X'**" is where I believe I need to pass in the record ID from the URL parameter needs to be set.

```
public class UploadAttachmentController {

public String selectedType {get;set;} //** original code
//    public Boolean selectedAwesomeness {get;set;} ** Oringial code
//    public String description {get;set;} ** Oringial code
public String cof {get;set;}
//    private Contact contact {get;set;} **Oringinal code
private Stage_Library__c stage {get;set;} //new code pointing to custom object
public Integer selectRoundRequired {get;set;}
public String fileName {get;set;}
public Blob fileBody {get;set;}


public UploadAttachmentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)  { 
    this.stage = (Stage_Library__c)controller.getRecord();
}   

/* Original code... this relates to Public get;set methods
// creates a new Contact_Attachment__c record
private Database.SaveResult saveCustomAttachment() {
    Contact_Attachment__c obj = new Contact_Attachment__c();
    obj.contact__c = contact.Id; 
    obj.description__c = description;
    obj.type__c = selectedType;
    obj.awesome__c = selectedAwesomeness;
    // fill out cust obj fields
    return Database.insert(obj);
*/

// creates a new Stage_Library__c record
private Database.SaveResult saveCustomAttachment() {
    Stage_Library__c obj = new Stage_Library__c();
//       obj.Name = Stage_Library__c.Id; 
//         obj.Course_of_Fire__c = cof;
    obj.Rounds_Required__c = selectRoundRequired;
    obj.Vicker_Type__c = selectedType;
    obj.id = 'a0G3000000H744X';
    // fill out cust obj fields
    return Database.update(obj);
}

// create an actual Attachment record with the Contact_Attachment__c as parent
private Database.SaveResult saveStandardAttachment(Id parentId) {
    Database.SaveResult result;

    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
    attachment.body = this.fileBody;
    attachment.name = this.fileName;
    attachment.parentId = parentId;
    // inser the attahcment
    result = Database.insert(attachment);
    // reset the file for the view state
    fileBody = Blob.valueOf(' ');
    return result;
}

/**
* Upload process is:
*  1. Insert new Contact_Attachment__c record
*  2. Insert new Attachment with the new Contact_Attachment__c record as parent
*  3. Update the Contact_Attachment__c record with the ID of the new Attachment
**/
public PageReference processUpload() {
    try {
        Database.SaveResult customAttachmentResult = saveCustomAttachment();

        if (customAttachmentResult == null || !customAttachmentResult.isSuccess()) {
            ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
              'Could not save attachment.'));
            return null;
        }

        Database.SaveResult attachmentResult = saveStandardAttachment(customAttachmentResult.getId());

        if (attachmentResult == null || !attachmentResult.isSuccess()) {
            ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
              'Could not save attachment.'));            
            return null;
        } else {
            // update the custom attachment record with some attachment info
            Stage_Library__c customAttachment = [select id from Stage_Library__c where id = :customAttachmentResult.getId()];
            customAttachment.File_Name__c = this.fileName;

//              customAttachment.[field name that saves attachment id] = attachmentResult.getId();
            update customAttachment;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        ApexPages.AddMessages(e);
        return null;
    }

//    return new PageReference('/'+ Stage_Library__c.Id); *this was the original
    return new PageReference('http://fifedom-developer-edition.na1.force.com/guns/Stage_Submission');
}

public PageReference back() {
    return new PageReference('/'+ Stage_Library__c.Id);
}     

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the following code:

```
obj.id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
```

which will pull in the Id parameter from the current URL.

See PageReference documentation for more on this if needed.
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_system_pagereference.htm

Comment: Perfect thanks!  that worked.  I'm not a APEX developer... just a copy and paste!  Much appreciated.